# Exception loading matrix from Matrix Market file using la4j

Tags: exception

I'd like to load a matrix from a Matrix Market file in my Java program using la4j library.

Using the method

```
Matrix.fromMatrixMarket(file);
```

where "file" is the content of the mtx file parsed via BufferedReader into String, it throws a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown majority: %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------.
at org.la4j.Matrix.fromMatrixMarket(Matrix.java:235)
at org.la4j.Test.main(Test.java:22)
```

I suppose because in mtx files that I've there is no information about majority, being squared matrix.

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

You could just pretend `row-major` to the first line in your MatrixMarket format to tell la4j you want treat this matrix as row-major.

Here is an example of a valid header for a row-major sparse matrix (i.e., `CRSMatrix`):

```
%%MatrixMarket matrix coordinate real general row-major
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I think it's not optimal to change all mtx files that I have adding "row-major". la4j also fails if there's some "%" comments below the header.

Comment: Right. The best way to solve it is to send a PR with improvements of `Matrix.fromMatrixMarket` method.